# Blue Prism - Trying to run automation in Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, blueprism, rpa

I am having blue prism architecture where my blue prism server and database server are in different machines which I access via taking remote desktop. 
          I scheduled my bot to run at server VM. Now when I am connected to VM using Remote Desktop Protocol and keep the window in monitoring mode(watching it), All my scheduled jobs works fine, But if I minimize that VM window (By minimizing RDP )or if I dont do RDP to VM machine, Then the automation stops and throws errors.

For checking purposes I also created a process on different server where Blue prism was installed and notices that everything works fine.

Is there any configuration that I am missing or any is there any other issue, Requesting all to let me know if there's a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I contacted blue prism team regarding this.
According to them there is problem in .Net framework or system is being corrupted.
I will let you all know exact solution once this issue is resolved....Thank you

Comment: did you manage to find the solution? It would be really helpful if you please share the solution

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Remote Desktop is officially unsupported by Blue Prism as a remote access utility, as it modifies the behavior of the automation when not being observed.

There are alternatives listed in the [official documentation on this topic](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-11/v6%20Data%20Sheet%20-%20Remote%20Access%20Tools.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.....For checking purposes I also created a process on different server where Blue prism was installed and notices that everything works fine.
I will post the solution once it is resolve...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong about this, but I think I was having issues with this as well and the problem lies with the way in which Windows are using the RDP. If you use any other Remote Desktop tool (WMware, Amazon Workspaces) then you'll be fine. If you have no other option that Windows RDP then I'm afraid you'll just have to keep that window open an not minimised.

Answer (score 1):

2 things here : 
  1) To solve all these kinds of issues please use the Login agent. Its best suited when you have control room and runtime resource mechanism.
2) If you are using surface automation for spying then screen resolution plays a very big role. So you can not minimize the screen during automation. Please check the screen resolution when you are training the bot and then again when you are actually running the bot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in the fact that if no one is actively connecting to the VM, the VM will go to 'sleep' mode. This essentially means the screen will go black and any visual elements required by any automation tool (including BluePrism) won't be able to be spied any more and hence an exception in thrown.

A common way to resolve this is to 'mock' an active session, by using tools like Caffeine. 
Other than that there is currently little you can do. If there is an ideal solution, I would be very interested in this myself too!

Comment: thank you for the reply.....I will try
I will post the solution once it is resolve...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Login agent on your VM and your problem will be solved. Also make sure you trigger your job from Control room.