# Running RPA UI interactions in a virtualized environment

Tags: virtual-machine, multiple-monitors, rpa, rpa-express

I've built several bots using RPA Express which are operating successfully so long as there is a display attached (local or via RDP) to enable the UI interactions. However, the UI interactions fail as soon as the RDP connection is lost. I'm looking to run the bots unattended on VMs, but can't seem to get around this issue.

I have had some luck using tscon upon logging off an RDP session, but the results are inconsistent and the likelihood of the 'console' display failing increases the longer that the RDP session is logged out.

I'm looking for a reliable virtual monitor solution that I can implement in a VM environment. Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the same issue people are experiencing with another RPA tool, Blue Prism ([see her](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52589198/4507417)).

I would try with another remote tool than Windows RDP. I have been using VMWare and Amazon Workspaces with no problems.